# Can i use alias in where clause?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT sum(st.stock_in) - sum(st.stock_out) as'stock_qty',
p.product_name,p.product_limit
FROM stock  as st 
join products as p 
on p.product_id=st.product_id
where 'stock_qty' < 'p.product_limit'   
GROUP BY st.product_id
```

I Have two Tables Products and Stock.

Products Table: Product_id, Product_name and Product_limit

Stock: stock_id, Product_id, stock_in, stock_out

From above query i get all the records, but I want to get only those records who product limit is reached or below.

if product 1 has 50 product_limit and stock reached the 50 limit or below the 50 so get me those records.

Suggest me best solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot:

- Use an alias in a `where` clause.
- Use aggregation functions in the `where` clause.

Although comparing two strings is pretty much not ever recommended, it is allowed.

But, you want a `having` clause anyway, so the question in your title is irrelevant.  Try this:

```
select sum(st.stock_in) - sum(st.stock_out) as stock_qty,
       p.product_name, p.product_limit
from stock st join
     products p 
     on p.product_id = st.product_id
group by p.product_name, p.product_limit
having stock_qty < p.product_limit  ;
```

Note that I changed the `group by` to match the columns being selected in the `select`.  That is also a good practice.

Comment: Thanks its work for me